# Porque no funciona el paquete chalk de npm en está aplicación?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Está aplicación muestra en la consola los archivos y carpeta del corriente directorio o de alguno en particular pasado como argumento. Cuando el elemento dentro del directorio es una carpeta debe resaltarse con `bold` pero no lo está haciendo y tampoco con colores;

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const path = require('path');
  
// Method 
const { lstat } = fs.promises;

const targetDir = process.argv[2] || process.cwd();

fs.readdir(targetDir, async (err, filenames) => {
  // EITHER
  // err === an error object, wich means something went wrong 
  // OR
  // err === null, wich means everything is OK

  if (err) {
    // error handling code here
    console.log(err);
  }

  const statPromises = filenames.map(filename => {
    return lstat(path.join(targetDir, filename));
  });
  
  const allStats = await Promise.all(statPromises);

  for (let stats of allStats) {
    const index = allStats.indexOf(stats);
    
    if (stats.isFile()) {
      console.log(filenames[index]);
    } else {
      console.log(chalk.bold(filenames[index]));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que obtienes en consola y qué es lo que deberías obtener?

Comment: Lo que obtengo en consola es una lista de todos los elementos pero no resalta con el estilo bold a las carpetas como es de esperar.